# Answerathon meets Best Answer Contest--I'm here to fund it! (CLOSED)

Tags: discussion, answer-contest, answerathon

## וְגַ֣ם ׀ אֲנִ֣י שָׁמַ֗עְתִּי אֶֽת־נַאֲקַת֙ בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל

(Exodus 6:5; Cf. 3:7,9)

I noticed some discussion surrounding those answer contests that would occur around here on occasion. I am here today to act benevolently and turn slightly to those bygone days.

#### Here's how I envisioned the contest:

The contest will last for twelve days. This is so that when six days have already elapsed, those who have only just heard about it will have a chance to join.

The starting date will be 24 of Teves, this Friday the 8th. The concluding day will be 6 of Shevat, the 19th of January. The points will be awarded the following day, on Wednesday, *Besiyata Deshemaya*. I presume that the time zones will follow the Stack Exchange network as was implemented in the past (as I recall).

#### Objective

The objective is to collect the largest amount of collective upvotes by answering questions on Mi Yodeya. Therefore, theoretically, if your answer received thousands of votes, you would be able to win with that single answer.

**This is important to note: A qualifying answer must have a minimum of 3 votes.** This is to prevent abuse. These are 3 upvotes that any given answer you 'submit' i.e. answer must have to qualify. This means that the public appearance of the votes must show a 3 or higher. Once a question passes this threshold it can qualify for your personal sum of total upvotes. If an answer has 3 upvotes and later receives a downvote which brings its value to 2, it will be disqualified. If you feel that this threshold of abuse prevention is too large, please leave a comment or an answer to engage the community's sentiments regarding this matter.

Let's review: Suppose user x has 10 answers each with 5 upvotes visible to the public, that user will then have a sum of 50 points towards winning.

I have not seen it necessary to limit the contest to answers for questions asked during a particular period of time in the history of this website.

I expect a participating contestant to post an answer for themselves, as well as regularly update it to keep score of their standings in the contest, and so that there is a mitigation of confusion. In the past we have used a single answer to keep track of the contestants, I don't think that is a good route to take for this one.

There are several levels of prizes, therefore it is important to the know exactly where each contestant stands. Additionally, it is a central location to catalogue answers which others may want to vote on.

- First prize points 1500 - Winner: [Harel13](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5368/16706)
- Second prize points 750 - Winner: [Dov](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5367/16706)
- Third prize points  350 - Winner: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5372/16706)
- Fourth prize points 200 - Winner: [רבות מחשבות](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5369/16706)
- Fifth prize point 100 - Winner: [Kazi bácsi](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5373/16706)

#### Trust?

If you inspect [my profile](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/16706/dr-shmuel?tab=reputation&sort=graph) you will notice that I have a long history of handing out exorbitant amounts of bounty. Furthermore, you will notice that because of that my ranking has rarely soared very high, usually settling down to the same homeostasis.

#### Theme song

I am adding a new element to this contest, which, as I recall, did not previously exist: An official theme song of the contest. The purpose of which may indeed be quite trivial, I'd like to propose one nonetheless. Suppose one would like to excel into the upper realms of this contest, but feels as if that goal is currently difficult to reach. Thus, do I propose, to listen to the theme song to focus one's abilities and maintain the motivation to continue moving forward. I imagined an engaged partaker of this contest speedily navigating a Sefaria webpage with a dozen sources while intently fixed onto the melodies in Zusha'a East Shtetl (our theme song: http://y2u.be/ub8r9NIiu14).

I'm sure I've missed many things here--let us know!

Comment: Actually I believe there is some sort of limit about handing out bounties in one day--we'll have to work on that.

Comment: I'm happy to hand out since of the bounties. Lmk.

Comment: I don't really like Zusha...any chance of changing the theme song? :D

Comment: As a band, or that particular song.? I am quite fond of that song :)@Harel13

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Both. But it's okay, you do you. This is your idea, after all. The general idea of having a theme song is nice.

Comment: @Harel13 I think we can add a co-song. Feel free to add one with decent descriptor--This is the contest of the People!

Comment: Is there a reason when I tried to post my points so far as an answer it reverted to a comment?

Comment: Perhaps the text is not long enough for an "answer". That is why I added the filler text on mine. @Dov But I cannot confirm this.

Comment: Does this include receiving new points for old answers?

Comment: @Harel13 It does not; only answers produced during the contest window.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel - thanks it worked

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel - if I updated an answer that already had two points and I since received a further three points does that qualify for 3 points or you have to start from zero?

Comment: If the it was answered since the contest has begun it is fair game,otherwise it is not@Dov

Comment: Does voting on answers have a specific meaning?

Comment: @DoubleAA No, the answers were just a convenient location to organize or collect the data

Comment: I see. Having the votes mean "thank you for helping people with quality answers" is a good idea.

Comment: I was thinking it as a cheer on the runners idea, but that works too. Either way I am not sure if we are reinventing the upvote here. I assume there haven't been votes yet because folks may have came to the conclusion which I answered to you, but I think your idea is swell.

Comment: Unless someone would like to suggest another aspect of significance to receiving the most upvotes..

Comment: So when is the contest officially over? 2021-01-19 at 23:59:59 UTC? I'm assuming that it's the vote tallies at that time which will determine the final rankings?

Comment: @JoelK Yes! Seems like 2 PM in NY and around 9 in JM

Comment: I think 7PM in NY, and 2AM on January 20th in Jerusalem

Comment: Post-Answerathon discussion thread [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5377/post-answerathon-discussion).

Answer (score 4):

@Dov Total: 42 points

- 1 ([6 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119451/halachic-status-of-beefalo/119453#119453))
- 2 ([3 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119483/22152))
- 3 ([6 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119512/22152))
- 4 ([3 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119477/22152))
- 5 ([3 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119521/22152))
- 6 ([6 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119530/22152))
- 7 ([3 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119566/22152))
- 8 ([6 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119573/22152))
- 9 ([3 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119600/22152))
- 10 ([3 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119559/22152))

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel thank you for a really wonderful competition. It was a great fun! And a true chance to be להגדיל תורה ולהאדירה! Yasher Kochacha!

Answer (score 4):

Harel13 Total: 46 points

- 1 ([6 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119469/20472))
- 2 ([6 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119491/20472))
- 3 ([4 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79102/if-dont-aspire-to-be-a-general-cannot-be-a-simple-soldier/119495#119495))
- 4 ([5 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/113891/which-of-the-zugos-were-in-charge-during-the-chanukah-story/119509#119509))
- 5 ([6 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105397/sources-on-the-rogochover-and-islam/119517#119517))
- 6 ([3 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119549/20472))
- 7 ([6 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119575/20472))
- 8 ([3 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119604/20472))
- 9 ([4 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119535/20472))
- 10 ([3 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119474/20472))

What is the "inyan" of this: (temporary filler text)?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> See comments below.

Comment: Lol! If you have too little text in the answer it reverts to a comment so we put 'temporary filler text' to take it up to the requisite number of words...

Comment: @Dov Ah, thank you! :D I didn't think of that. It's like putting 15 char to fill up short comments.

Comment: Naah, I heard its a real holy inyan

Comment: Wow @Harel13 you're a machine! I can't keep up! Yasher kochacho! :-)

Comment: @Dov It's probably because I likely have more time than most people here...

Comment: Don't forget to add you piece on the three authors of tehillim!

Comment: @Dov Thanks, I didn't. It's an answer from prior to the contest. I just edited it a little bit yesterday.

Comment: Oh shame it was pretty epic!!

Comment: @Harel13 - Really strong finish! I took my foot off the pedal Well done!

Comment: Thank you @Dov, I'm quite shocked myself, considering we were neck to neck most of the time. Yishar Koach to you!

Answer (score 3):

רבות מחשבות, Total: 24 points

- 1 ([7 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119472/16354))
- 2 ([9 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119597/16354))
- 3 ([4 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119475/16354))
- 4 ([4 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66746/which-manuscript-of-the-mishna-did-the-bartenura-check/119616#119616))

(Temporary filler text)

Answer (score 2):

Dr. Shmuel Total: 8 points

- 1 [(4 points)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119445/16706)
- 2 [(4 points)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119514/16706)

(Temporary filler text)

Answer (score 2):

JoelK, Total: 29 points

- 1 ([6 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119515/14850))
- 2 ([5 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119511/14850))
- 3 ([4 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119537/14850))
- 4 ([4 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119533/14850))
- 5 ([3 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119551/14850))
- 6 ([7 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119558/14850))

Answer (score 2):

Kazi bácsi – 8 points

- 1 ([8 points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119516/15256))

---

<sup>I don't think that I'll eventually win, but it's a really nice initiative and [the important thing is not to win, but to take part](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Pierre_de_Coubertin).</sup>

Comment: I suppose my biggest satisfaction is to have tied with @Dr.Shmuel for the fifth place! It was a great initiative that put emphasis on quality besides quantity, which resulted in great answers. I'm really looking forward to future editions of the contest!